# "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'" error when installing a python package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install a python package DMRG101 on Linux Zorin. I get this package from GitHub https://github.com/iglpdc/dmrg101. I have python 2.7.12 and python 3.5.2 installed. I tried to install this package using

`python setup.py install`

but it is giving me the following error

```
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running install_lib
    running install_egg_info
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        requires = [],
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 613, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 971, in run_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install_egg_info.py", line 46, in finalize_options
        to_filename(safe_version(self.distribution.get_version()))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install_egg_info.py", line 88, in safe_version
        version = version.replace(' ','.')
    AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

how can I eliminate this error?

Answer (score 1):

I just go to install_egg_info.py and modify this line as:

```
version = str(version).replace(' ','.')
```

Then, rerun the install command again and it works.